# OpenCV Box Blur algorithm for GrayScale image

Tags: c++, opencv, blur

I have used sources such as this -
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296679/what-does-kernel-size-mean
and this-
http://amritamaz.net/blog/understanding-box-blur

in order to understand Box blur what I understand is, when reading in an image in openCV you need to create a copy of that image with a border to accommodate for the kernal size. the kernal size for me is 7 * 7 meaning I would need a border around the whole image that extends by 3.

What I have done is read my image in grayscale, created an all black border on the image, created a 7 * 7 kernal and written the algorithm in order to change the value of each pixel to create a blurring effect.

What I am getting is a very noisy colored image:

[output of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rW7w.png)

Any advise about why I would be getting this instead of a blurred black and white image is greatly appriciated

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;
const int rowSize = 7;
const int colSize = 7;
int top, bottom, left, right;
int borderType = BORDER_CONSTANT;
const char* window_name = "copyMakeBorder Demo";
RNG rng(12345);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Declare variables
    Mat src, dst, wborder;
    Mat kernel;
    Point anchor;
    double delta;
    int ddepth;
    float sum;
    int kernel_size;
    const char* window_name = "filter2D Demo";
    const char* imageName = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "lena.jpg";
    Mat src_br;
    float matrix[rowSize][colSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 1.0/49;
        }
    }
    // Loads an image
    src = imread(samples::findFile(imageName), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); // Load an image 8uc3 //read in gray 8uc1
    Mat image_gray;
    cvtColor(src, image_gray, CV_8UC1);
    //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     //   imshow(window_name, image_gray);
    //}

    if (src.empty())
    {
        printf(" Error opening image\n");
        printf(" Program Arguments: [image_name -- default lena.jpg] \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // Initialize arguments for the filter
    anchor = Point(-1, -1);
    delta = 0;
    ddepth = -1;
    // Loop - Will filter the image with different kernel sizes each 0.5 seconds
    int ind = 0;
    // Initialize arguments for the filter
    top = (int)(rowSize / 2); bottom = top;
    left = (int)(colSize / 2); right = left;
    
        Scalar value(rng.uniform(0,0));
        copyMakeBorder(image_gray, wborder, top, bottom, left, right, borderType, value);
       // for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       //     imshow(window_name, wborder);
       // }
        cv::Mat trying = wborder.clone();
    for (;;)
    {
        // Update kernel size for a normalized box filter
        kernel_size = 7;
      
        for (int x = 3; x < wborder.rows - 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 3; y < wborder.cols - 3; y++) {
                sum = 0;
                for (int i = -3; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = -3; j < 3; j++) {
                        sum = sum + matrix[j + 3][i + 3] * wborder.at<uint>(x - j, y - i); // two fix
                       
                        int pixelColor = wborder.at<uint>(x, y);
                        
                    }

                }
                trying.at<uint>(x,y) = (int)sum; //change to uint
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            imshow(window_name, trying);
        }
        char c = (char)waitKey(500);
        // Press 'ESC' to exit the program
        if (c == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
        ind++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: convolution need to be done in single step, to the whole image. (you cannot read and write to same image in a loop)

Comment: btw, the `kernalsize`, `pixelColor` is not used at all, it'd be better to clean up the code before post. see [mcve]

Comment: @appleapple im confused - I have to have the wborder.at<uint>(x,y) = (int)sum; in the loop cause this changes the value of each pixel

Comment: @‌loaf you need to write to new image.

Comment: @‌loaf and your `matrix` has weight `1/49` but you only sample `9` pixel. I'd suggest first try just adding them and do a divide (and drop the matrix for now).

Comment: @appleapple Okay i changed the loop so that it will go through the whole size of the matrix and im writing to a different matrix and the image no longer shows up when i run: im editing my question so you can see the change i made

Comment: @‌loaf I see no specific change make it doesn't show the image, but you probably should not show the window 10 times.